# Programmatically update or add a user's avatar

Tags: users, 8

I'm trying to update the user avatar in my custom module. Which method shall I use to update the image in db as well as to move the file to public directory?

Thanks.

Comment: The user_picture field installed by the standard profile is an image field. If this is what is on your site, then normal Entity API and File API operations can be done.

Comment: When using `file_save_data()` ,what should be given as the first parameter? As shown here (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.module/function/file_save_data/8) the parameter should be  **string $data: A string containing the contents of the file.** Is this the _id_ of the file type?

Answer (score 3):

The file gets stored to `file_managed` table like this:

```
// Programmatically create files.
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
$file = File::create([
  'uid' => 1,
  'filename' => $_FILES['file_id']['name'],
  'uri' => 'public://pictures/' . $_FILES['file_id']['name'],
  'status' => 1,
]);
$file->save();
```

And I manually updated `user__user_picture` table which is referring to the `fid` in the above table.

Finally I ended up with `move_uploaded_file` to store the image to the filesystem. 
I'll proceed with this approach until I find a better way to do the same.

http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/47/create-a-file-drupal-8

Comment: This working form me
$user = user_load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$user->set('user_picture', $file);
$user->save();

Answer (score 3):

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
$user->set('user_picture', $fid);
$user->save();
```

Comment: I have used the above code and its working fine for me. There is no need of file library `use Drupal\file\Entity\File;` to update user picture. Simply load the user by their `uid` and pass the `fid` or form file upload id in above code. It will automatically update the user profile picture.